# Apache LimitRequestFieldSize Directive does not work

Tags: apache, http

I'm running my website on apache 2.2 and when the HTTP request header size is above 8K I get a HTTP 400 error -

**Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.

Size of a request header field exceeds server limit.

cookie /n**

And the error in Apache error_log is -
`[Fri Jul 24 18:52:56 2015] [error] [client XX.XX.XX.XX] request failed: error reading the headers`

This is expected but when I set allowed limit to 16k by -

```
LimitRequestFieldSize 16380
```

I still get the same HTTP 400 error on the browser but this time I don't see any error apache error_log.

I have tried using higher values with LimitRequestLine and LimitRequestFields but it doesn't work. Is there any thing I'm missing here ?

Comment: Perhaps it's a different setting? There's `LimitRequestBody` e.g.

Comment: @Pekka웃 LimitRequestBody is for the HTTP request message and not the headers so changing it won't help.

Comment: curios, did you succeed in fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a maddening time dealing with this, but for me I finally made it work by putting `LimitRequestFieldSize` at the top of my conf file, rather than the bottom.